# Jquery slidedown when start typing in form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form, and when the user starts typing in his company name, then a div appears (slidedown) where the user can fill in his company information.

Now is the problem, that when the value is more than " " or something, the div will slide down. BUT, i gave the input a value in the code, so the div will appear when the page loads.

I tried this, but didn't work:(

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#NewCustomerDiv input[name=CompanyName]').keyup(function(){

 if(!$(this).val() || "test"){
      $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideUp("slow");
 }
 else{
$('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideDown("slow");
 }
});
if($('#NewCustomerDiv input[name=CompanyName]').val()){
     $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideDown("slow");
}
});
</script> 

<div id="NewCustomerDiv" >
<label>Company name: </label>
<input type="text" name="CompanyName" value="test"/>
<br />

<div id="CustomerCompanyDiv" style="display:none">        <label>Company name:</label>
Here comes the input form for the company information.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but i've figured out this from what i understand you want like this?

```
$('#NewCustomerDiv input[name=CompanyName]').keyup(function () {
   if($(this).val().length > 0) {
       if($(this).val() == "test")
           $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideUp("slow");
       else        
           $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideDown("slow");
   } else {      
       $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideUp("slow");
   }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7NTEk/2/)

Comment: No sorry, when the user doesn't type in the form, the div doesn't have to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PLACEHOLDER Parameter to inform users of the functionality of a form element:

```
<input type="text" name="CompanyName" placeholder="Type test to slide up"/>
```

Comment: but what i want is that when the user starts typing in CompanyName, the other forms will slide down

Answer (score 0):

ok try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Ebt/3/)

Your modified script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#NewCustomerDiv input[name=CompanyName]').keyup(function(){

 if($(this).val()==""){
      $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideUp("slow");
 }
 else{
    $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideDown("slow");
 }
});
if($('#NewCustomerDiv input[name=CompanyName]').val()){
     $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideDown("slow");
}
});
```